# Problems using parse.push.subscribe with trigger.io

Tags: trigger.io, parse-platform

I have successfully (and easily) added push notifications to my trigger.io application due to the supplied notification support and that Parse.com makes it a breeze. However, I can only broadcast without channels because when I use `parse.push.subscribe(channel, ...)` to try to subscribe to a channel I get this error:

```
error occurred: undefined:[unknown lineno]: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: parse
```

The trigger.io docs are not extensive around this. Anyone got it to work? Throw me some hints, please.

Comment: No, I'm still on the hunt. Nothing I try works. Do you have the same problem? Please upvote the question if so.

Comment: @PEZ could it be you're using just `parse.push.subscribe` in your JS? Note that all modules and partners are hung off the global forge object, e.g.: `forge.parse.push.subscribe(...)`

Comment: I've tried accessing it from the forge object too but `forge.parse` is undefined.

Comment: Could you zip up your src directory and send it to support@trigger.io in that case? `forge.parse` *should* be there if you have it enabled in the `partners` section of your config.json...

Comment: I've added `partners` as a sibling to `modules`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our documentation was lacking here - thanks for highlighting it @PEZ!

The Parse methods in Trigger.io are available under forge.partners.parse, e.g.:

```
forge.partners.parse.push.subscribe("beta-testers",
function () {
  forge.logging.info("subscribed to beta-tester push notifications!");
},
function (err) {
  forge.logging.error("error subscribing to beta-tester notifications: "+
    JSON.stringify(err));
});
```

I've updated our docs with some examples.